# .Net5 FocusAsync() not compiling

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-5

I am new to and playing with MS Blazor on the new .Net5 framework.  I am attempting to set the focus of a text element when a button is clicked.  I have seen this code elsewhere and trying to get it to compile:

```
<button @onclick="() => textInput.FocusAsync()">Set focus</button><input @ref="textInput"/>
```

VS2019 is throwing an error on the textInput value: The name 'textInput' does not exist in the current context.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `@code` section you need to create a property/variable called `textInput` which is of type `ElementReference`. There's then an extension method on `ElementReference` that's in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components` namespace called `FocusAsync` which you should be able to call.

```
<button @onclick="() => textInput.FocusAsync()">Set focus</button><input @ref="textInput"/>

@code {
   private ElementReference textInput;
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!